# How to make partition inside Quicksort function?

Tags: c++, quicksort

This is the question that I am working on

---

// Sorts an array arr[low..high]

```
randQuickSort(arr[], low, high)
```

1. If `low >= high`, then `EXIT`.
2. While pivot 'x' is not a Central Pivot.

(i) Choose uniformly at random a number from [low..high].
Let the randomly picked number number be x.

(ii) Count elements in `arr[low..high]` that are smaller
than `arr[x]`. Let this count be sc.

(iii) Count elements in `arr[low..high]` that are greater
than `arr[x]`. Let this count be gc.

(iv) Let `n = (high-low+1)`. If `sc >= n/4` and
`gc >= n/4`, then x is a central pivot.
3. Partition arr[low..high] around the pivot x.

4. // Recur for smaller elements

   randQuickSort(arr, low, sc-1)
5. // Recur for greater elements

   randQuickSort(arr, high-gc+1, high)

---

I have done to the (iv) part and then stucked at 3. which is to Partition arr[low..high] around the pivot and the problem is that my professor told me to mmake partition inside the randQuickSort function which I have search anywhere and the only example I got is seperated function

This is the code I have done so far

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void randQuickSort(int arr[], int low, int high);
int main(){
    int arr[10] = {1,2,12,3,68,6,10,32,34,0};
    randQuickSort(arr,0,9);
    for(int i: arr)
        cout << i;
}
void randQuickSort(int arr[], int low, int high){
    int x,sc,gc,n;
    if( low >= high )
        exit(0);
    while(true){
        x = rand%10;
        for(int i = low; i <= high; i++){
            if(arr[i] < x)
                sc++;
            else if(arr[i] > x)
                gc++;
        }
        n = (high-low+1);
        if(sc >= n/4 && gc >= n/4)
            break;
    }
    randQuickSort(arr,low,sc-1);
    randQuickSort(arr,high-gc+1,high);
}
```

I would like some explanation on how do I go from here because I don't know how should I start.

Comment: `x = arr[rand()];` what's the value range of `rand()` and which values are valid indexes for `arr`?

Comment: The [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) function returns a value between `0` and [`RAND_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX). The value of `RAND_MAX` is *at least* `32767`. Which is way out of bounds of your small array.

Comment: Also the loop `for(int i = low; i <= high; i++)` will make `i` equal to `high`, and `high` is the count of elements in the array, not the top index. So `i` can go out of bounds as well. Going out of bounds in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Oops Seem like I accidently do that let me fix it a bit. I meant to make it randomly pick the value inside the array